# Prove that when $|x|\geq M_1+M_0t, u(x,t)=0$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, estimation, wave-equation, hyperbolic-equations

> For the following Cauchy problem:
> \begin{cases} \partial^2_tu-a^2(x,t)\partial^2_xu=f(x,t), x\in\mathbb{R},t>0\\u(x,0)=\varphi(x), \partial_t u(x,0)=\psi(x), x\in\mathbb{R},\end{cases}
> where
> \begin{cases} \|a\|_{L^\infty}+\|\partial a\|_{L^\infty}\leq M_0\\ \varphi(x)=\psi(x)=0, |x|\geq M_1\\f(x,t)=0, |x|>M_1+M_0t.\end{cases}
> Prove that when $|x|\geq M_1+M_0t, u(x,t)=0$.

I just learned the *energy esimate* of $a$ being a constant. For the problem, it seems the first equation multiplying $\partial_t u$ cannot be writen as the form of divergence. I don't know how to handle the additional terms by using remaining conditions.

Some calculation I have done:
$$
2\int_{K_\tau}f(x,t)\partial_t u \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}t=\int_{K_\tau}[2\partial_t^2u\partial_t u-2a^2(x,t)\partial_x^2u\partial_t u ]\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}t
$$
$$
2\partial_t^2u\partial_t u-2a^2(x,t)\partial_x^2u\partial_t u=\partial_t[(\partial_t u)^2+a^2(x,t)(\partial_xu)^2]-\partial_x[2a^2(x,t)\partial_xu\partial_tu]\\+2a(x,t)\partial_ta(x,t) (\partial_xu)^2-4a(x,t)\partial_xa(x,t) \partial_xu\partial_tu
$$
I don't kwon what to do with the last two terms. Or multiple other term instead of $2\partial_t u$?

Appreciate any help,hint, or recommendation of relevant textbooks.

Comment: Why don't you write out what you have done so we can see where the issue lies.

Comment: Added some calculation. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you defining the energy as $$E(t)=\int_{\Bbb{R}}(\partial_t u(x,t))^2+(\partial_xu(x,t))^2\mathrm dx$$
?

Comment: I think the energy should be $$E(t)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}(\partial_t u(x,t))^2+a^2(x,t)(\partial_t u(x,t))^2 \mathbb{d}x.$$

Comment: @user823011 yes, that's right. Thanks